# p/invoke marshal a struct with string arrays

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

I'm calling a C dll from C#, and can't find the right way to marshal the returned struct.

In my ConvertConfigStructToDico which performs the marshalling, I correctly read the first size_t field but crash when reading the char** with my ConvertStringArray. Yet I tested the latter on a 'char** method()' and it works, so I wonder if I didn't incorrectly advance my pointer to the wrong location on the line *IntPtr p = args + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ulong));*

I'd be grateful if anybody could assist on that matter...

The C method (external one, I cannot change it):

```
// By design, the returned length is always 1.
configStruct *Config_enumerate(size_t *length);

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    char **keys;
    char **vals;
} configStruct;
```

My C# code:

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, string>> GetConfig(string args = "")
{
   // By design, the returned length will always be 1.
   ulong length = 0;
   IntPtr configStructArray = Config_enumerate(ref length);
   var list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>((int)length);

   // Correct because length is always 1.
   var dico = ConvertConfigStructToDico(configStructArray);
   list.Add(dico);

   return list;
}
[DllImport("external", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern IntPtr Config_enumerate(ref ulong length);

static Dictionary<string, string> ConvertConfigStructToDico(IntPtr args)
{
    //typedef struct
    //{
    //  size_t size;
    //  char** keys;
    //  char** vals;
    //}
    //configStruct;

    // Works fine, I get the right size.
    ulong size = (ulong)Marshal.ReadInt64(args);    //size_t is ulong in Win64 and uint in x86
    // Advance pointer to next field
    IntPtr p = args + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ulong));
    // BUG: ConvertStringArray will incorrectly read the first string then crash (access violation). Is my point "args" pointer incorrect?
    string[] keys = ConvertStringArray(p, (uint)size);    // This frees unmanaged memory.
    p += (int)size * IntPtr.Size;
    string[] values = ConvertStringArray(p, (uint)size);  // This frees unmanaged memory.
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(args);

    Dictionary<string, string> dico = new Dictionary<string, string>((int)size);
    for (int i = (int)size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        dico[keys[i]] = values[i];
        return dico;
}

/// <summary>
/// Converts an unmanaged string array specified by its pointer, into an array of managed <see cref="String"/>, and cleans up unmanaged memory afterwards.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args">The pointer to the unmanaged string array</param>
/// <param name="length">The number of items in the unmanaged string array</param>
/// <returns></returns>
static string[] ConvertStringArray(IntPtr args, uint length)
{
    string[] array = new string[length];
    IntPtr p = args;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        var strPtr = (IntPtr)Marshal.PtrToStructure(p, typeof(IntPtr));
        array[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(strPtr);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(strPtr);
        p += IntPtr.Size;
    }

    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(args);
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Your tags are confusing. If you are calling Native/Unamanaged Code, that has nothing to do with C++ CLI/C++ .NET. Those two cases would be MANAGED code, so the whole work need for P/Invoke would be non-existant.

Comment: It depends what happens in your C code. Can you show the C code? (also note your code is hardcoded for X64)

Comment: One extra level of indirection required, use Marshal.ReadIntPtr() to get the pointer to the array.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thanks, that was it! First question on SO, and a good answer so fast.... :)

Comment: @Christopher: you're right, I edited my post. Thank you

Comment: This question is getting edited and re-activated for no good reason.  If you want to keep it around then you need to post the solution you used and mark it as the answer.